# How is Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) different from value.toString()?

Tags: javascript, prototype

From what I understand, the former will:

1. Find the `toString` method on Object
2. call it on `value` but with `this` bound to `value`

And `value.toString()` will.

1. Find the `toString` method somewhere in `value`'s prototype chain
2. Call `toString` on value bound with `this` as value via the function invocation pattern

So the difference is if there is an overridden `toString` method in value...  it will use that.

My question is:

1. Is that the only difference?
2. Conversely, is this pattern the standard pattern to use if we want to be guaranteed we're calling `Parent`'s method and not potentially some overridden by `Child`?  (In this case Parent = Object, Child = the class value comes from, if we're thinking classically, and method = toString.)

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph.  What are you asking?

Comment: @ExplosionPills thanks, edited to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.prototype.toString.apple(value)` will let you call on `null`, while you use `null.toString()`, it will produce an error.

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(null);
>"[object Null]"

null.toString();
>TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null
```

Comment: That's not really the point. The proper `.toString()` evaluation of `null` isn't `"[object Null]"`, but rather `"null"`. When you pass a value as the context of `Object.prototype.toString`, it gives you the value of its internal *[[Class]]* property, which is useful for type checking. [ECMAScript 9.8 ToString](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8)

Comment: Follow up question: when I type Object.prototype in the console, I see Object { } (implying that the prototype is an *empty* object), but I'm assuming that methods like toString() are in fact implemented in the Object.prototype. So why does it show that Object.prototype is an empty object?

Answer (score 5):

`Object.prototype.toString` can be a different method than `value.toString()` depending upon what the latter is.

```
> Object.prototype.toString.apply("asdfasdf")
"[object String]"
> "asdfasdf".toString()
"asdfasdf"
> Object.prototype.toString.apply(new Date)
"[object Date]"
> (new Date).toString()
"Tue Mar 05 2013 20:45:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

`.prototype[function].apply` (or `.call` or `.bind`) allow you to change the context of a method even though the context may not have such a method at all.

```
var o = {};
o.prototype = {x: function () { console.log('x'); }}
var y = {}
o.prototype.x.call(y)
y.x(); //error!
```

...so that is to say that

1. It's not the only difference
2. This doesn't necessarily have to do with a relationship between parent and child .. it just allows you to call one object's method (or any function) with a different object context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got this right. I don't usually see people calling `Object.prototype.toString` directly like that though (it usually makes some sense to let objects override their `toString` method) but its certainly very common and recommended for some other methods like `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Why is it recommended in the latter case?

Comment: When we use objects as "dumb hash-tables" you should use hasOwnProperty to see if a key is present (because we don't want to count things in the property chain). Using the "real" hasOwnProperty from Object.prototype protects against the case if someone adds "hasOwnProperty" as a key to the hash table.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString` is not a substitute for the `.toString()` method found on the other native prototypes. It's not comparable to doing `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` because there isn't a unique `.hasOwnProperty` method defined on any other prototype.